# Google Sheet formatting when emailing the data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to setup a script that emails the contents of a sheet while at the same time preserving the formatting/layout.

I have a script that sends out an email with the contents of the sheet. The problem is that the information that is email is just on one long line separated by commas, like this example:

b1,c1,d1,B2,c2,d2,b3,C3,d3,b4,c4,d4,b5,c5,d5,b6,c6,d6,b7,c7, etc

Ideally I would like the cell formatting to be preserved(the rows and columns) or simply be able to export a copy of the sheet and email that as an attachment or something. I'm open to ideas and suggestions just keep in mind that I am novice programmer. Any help is would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: share some codes snippets please which you are using in your application to send data.

Comment: +1 this question, I would love to know this also. The formatting is horrible by default.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, nobody is going to be able to figure out what you're doing that produces that line of output.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600638/google-script-copy-to-clipboard-and-mailto-questions/18645451#18645451) for a `getHtmlTable()` function that does a reasonably good job of replicating the format of a spreadsheet range for sending in an email.