# Google Apps Script how to copy a table from a sheet to a docs as if you manually copy-pasted it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can't seem to find the correct function to do that. 
I see that I can use appendTable(range.getValues()) to copy the values but I lose the formatting doing so and since I also have some =hyperlink() in the values they also get lost.
What I would like to have is a function that does exactly what a manual copy-paste does.

Does anyone know if such function exists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `getHtmlTable()` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600638/google-script-copy-to-clipboard-and-mailto-questions/18645451#18645451), and adapt it to build a Google Doc Table instead of HTML. Where the HTML table has the spreadsheet `tableFormat()` attributes turned into HTML style tags, you'd want `TableCell.setAttribute()` (and other `setX` things) used to make the table match the source spreadsheet as much as possible.

Comment: If you do use `getHtmlTable()`, be sure to [grab the code from the gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/6455765), which is more up-to-date.