# How to prevent Google Forms from converting form input to scientific notation format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I have a simple script set up that sends emails based on Google Form entries using a script-based VLookup to get the contact emails. In some cases, Google Forms converts longer numbers entered into the form field to scientific notation. A workaround I have been using is to enter an apostrophe before the number - for some reason this keeps the cell formatted to plaintext. I would like to find a solution that does not require this extra step.

The sheet has a form with a single field, eGCs. The eGCs field can contain ANY combination of letters and numbers and may be a multi-line string. The script sends an email to the user onFormSubmit with the eGCs field entry in the body of the email. The problem arises when I try to submit a very long string that is only numbers and the form entry variable is converted to scientific notation.

I need whatever the user enters in the eGCs field to appear EXACTLY as they entered it on both the Responses 1 sheet and in the body of the email that is sent. Here is the code:

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {

   var eGCs = e.values[1];
   var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

//Replace the Google Sheets formatted line breaks with HTML line breaks so they display properly in the email:
   eGCs = eGCs.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

//Send the email:   
   var subject = "This is only a test";
   var body = eGCs;
   MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body})
   return
   }
```

If I submit

```
6110523527643880
```

...into the form, the number is changed to scientific notation format and appears as `6.11052E+15` both on the sheet and in the email that is sent. If I submit a multi-line string such as:

```
6110523527643880
6110523527643880
6110523527643880
```

...then the script works fine and the form field entry is not converted (probably because Google does not consider it a number any more). I need it to appear exactly as entered whether or not the form entry is a single line or multiple lines.

Here is my [example sheet / script / form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mNLSPYwdlNGGenVtdUHOg5ZlQo7BeZeJWiD9i3EYkZI/edit#gid=254772788). It should be public, so please feel free to test it.

Comment: Is it forms or the spreadsheet that is converting it? Have you tried changing the format to in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi Spencer -  I am not sure. It is the same issue that this person is dealing with, if this helps: https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/docs/dMIAKVtuKW0/4P6w5KzeIu0J
My suspicion is that somewhere in the process Google is changing the cell back to "Automatic" format rather than "Plain Text". I have the entire column set to "Plain Text" format in the spreadsheet, but this does not seem to matter. I tried using the script suggested by someone in those comments, but still no luck.

Comment: I created a dummy sheet so you can see it in action yourself.  Added it to the original post at the top.

Comment: The forward tick makes the cell content text - that's a standard notation in Excel, Lotus 1-2-3, and even way back in VisiCalc. What your issue really is, though, is cell formatting in Sheets, completely independent from Forms. You could have a trigger function apply the appropriate formats using [`Range.setNumberFormats()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormats(Object)). WRT your comments about format being changed by submission... close! Submitting a form inserts a new row, which has automatic formatting.

Comment: Thank you for your input, Mogsdad. The solution at the bottom of the thread you copied does not work in this case because, as you said, a new row is being added to the sheet that does not retain the formatting applied to the rest of the column. 

As for your setNumberFormats() solution, would I be able to apply this to the newly created row before the onFormSubmit trigger sends the emails? Or would I need to move one of the triggers further up or down in the chain in order for this to work? I'm not sure I'm experienced enough with javascript to implement this without guidance unfortunately.

Comment: The only problem with the setNumberFormats solution, as far as I can tell, is that the information typed into the eGCs form field is never the same format or length, and is sometimes a mix of letters and numbers sometimes and other times all numbers.

Comment: Do you think there is a way to append the ' tick to the front of the eGCs variable before  the form responses get to the sheet and before the emails are sent?

Comment: Answer: Nope. It just appends a tick to the scientific notation format of the numbers

Comment: If the formatting in an existing row is what you want, use `getFormats()` on it, then `setFormats()` on the new row. But your comments have now wandered into yet-another question (or your original question isn't clear): How to have formatted values in spreadsheet reflect in an email? (answer: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18645451/1677912).)

Comment: PS: To respond to a user in a comment, use `@` before their name so they get notified.

Comment: @MogsDad blah. This is getting into territory that I was hoping to not have to traverse: A non onFormSubmit triggered SendMail script, which is what we were using for this purpose before I decided to try and make the process simpler. It seems ridiculous to me that there is no simple solution for this - why the heck would Google assume that we want a number in Scientific format?

Comment: @Mogsdad I thought my question was pretty clear so apologies if this is not the case - my script sends an email with contents based on Google Form submissions. I want the data / strings entered by the user to appear as exactly what they entered with no formatting changes, both on the spreadsheet and in the email (I don't believe these are exclusive, but perhaps they are?)

Comment: They are exclusive, for similar reasons. If you type the content of each field in a form submission into a spreadsheet with default formatting, you'll find that some cells remain plain text, some get interpreted as numbers, and others as dates. Unless formatting is set first, the sheet contents won't look like what you typed in. That's what's going on when a form submission arrives. When a script reads a spreadsheet, it gets _values_, without formatting - same stuff, different pile. For that, though, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18645451/1677912), and follow to Github.

Comment: There's something very special about that 16-digit number, `6110523527643880`, I can't figure out what rule applies to make it display as an E. Type it into a spreadsheet cell, and it's converted to E-notation. Change the last `0` to any other digit, and it's left as an integer.  Increase the length by adding a digit anywhere, and it's left as an integer. Certainly a bug, which could be reported through the [Google Docs Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/docs).

Comment: Interesting. I took your advice and posted this issue onto the Google Docs Help Forum. Hopefully someone there has some answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form responses *in Forms* (as opposed to Spreadsheets) store responses as Strings. Your trigger function could grab the response from the form to get the string as entered by the respondent.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // Get response sheet. First version works only in contained script,
  // second works even in stand-alone scripts.
//  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();

  // Get URL of associated form & open it
  var formUrl = sheet.getParent().getFormUrl();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);

  // Get response matching the timestamp in this event
  var timestamp = new Date(e.namedValues.Timestamp);
  // NOTE: There is a race condition between the updates in Forms and Sheets.
  // Sometimes (often!) the Spreadsheet Form Submission trigger function is invoked
  // before the Forms database has completed persisting the new Responses. As
  // a result, we might get no results when asking for the most recent response. 
  // To work around that, we will wait and try again.
  var timeToGiveUp = 0;
  do {
    if (timeToGiveUp > 0) Utilities.sleep(1000); // sleep 1s on subsequent tries
    timeToGiveUp++;
    var responses = form.getResponses(timestamp);
  } while (responses.length == 0 && (timeToGiveUp < 3));
  Logger.log("time to give up "+timeToGiveUp);
  var response = responses[0]; // assume just one response matches timestamp
  var itemResponses = response.getItemResponses();
  var eGCsItemNumber = 1;  // Indicates where the question appears in the form
  var eGCs = itemResponses[eGCsItemNumber-1].getResponse().toString();

  // You now have exactly what the respondent typed, as a string.
  // It can be used as-is in an email, for example.
  var body = "The user entered: "+eGCs;
  MailApp.sendEmail(
     Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
     "This is only a test",
     body
   );

  // To preserve the value in the spreadsheet, we must
  // force it to remain a string by prepending a tick (')
  var eGCsCol = 2;
  e.range.offset(0,eGCsCol-1,1,1).setValue("'"+eGCs);
}
```

Note wrt **Race condition** comment: The actual work that was needed in this area of the code was a single line:

```
var responses = form.getResponses(timestamp);
```

While playing with this, I found that I was frequently receiving an exception, the same as noted in comments below this answer...

> Cannot find method getResponses(object)

It turned out that this only happened when the function was triggered by a form submission event, not when running from the editor/debugger with simulated events. That implies that, for a short period of time, the response we're trying to handle is not returned by the call to `getResponses()`.

Because of the way that shared documents are implemented, there is a *propagation delay* for any change... that's the time it takes for a change in one view of an asset to propagate to all other views.

In this situation, our trigger function has launched with a spreadsheet event, and then opens a view of the Form and tries to read the newest responses **before** that view contains them.

A simple work-around would be to `sleep()` for a period of time that would allow propagation to complete.

```
Utilities.sleep(5000);   // 5s pause
var responses = form.getResponses(timestamp);
```

Simple, yes - but inefficient, because we'd be waiting even when we didn't need to. A second problem would be determining how long was long enough... and what if that changed tomorrow?

The chosen work-around will retry getting responses only if it is not successful the first time. It will only wait when doing a retry. And it won't wait forever - there's a *limiting condition* applied, via `timeToGiveUp`. (We could have added an additional check for success after the loop, but since the next statement will through an exception if we've blown through our time limit, we can let it do the dirty work.)

```
var timeToGiveUp = 0;
do {
  if (timeToGiveUp > 0) Utilities.sleep(1000); // sleep 1s on subsequent tries
  timeToGiveUp++;
  var responses = form.getResponses(timestamp);
} while (responses.length == 0 && (timeToGiveUp < 3));
```

Lots more than one line of code, but more robust.

Comment: Thank you for continuing to work on a solution for this, Mogsdad. I will try to implement your code with mine and report back.

Comment: I received a Summary of failures:
6/17/15 3:27 PM onFormSubmit Cannot find method getResponses(object) - I added our code combined to the bottom of my question at the top so you can see what I tried.

Comment: Should itemResponses[2] be itemResponses[1] in this case since the eGCs column is now in column B on the simplified sheet?

Comment: I re-added the triggers and now I am getting the Summary of Failures: Failed to retrieve form responses. Please wait and try again. (line 8, file "Code"). I have to go right now, but thank you again for your help.

Comment: I feel like this is very close to the answer I am looking for. I just cannot figure out how to make this code work at the moment. I know that I need to store the form response as a variable like you have done above, but I am still getting the same Summary of Failures

Comment: My answer wasn't so much a "teach to fish" response, as "the fish are over there". Now, I've updated the answer with working code, so "here, have a fish"!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ivFma7E.gif

YES! It works! Thank you so much for your continued help, despite my sometimes frustrating naivety. This is the answer folks - I will update my original post to reflect this.

Comment: It does seem to fail intermittently, but I assume this is due to the reason you mentioned above. This is definitely the solution though, and I have marked it as solved. I will try to find a way to keep the summary of failures notification from showing up in the mean time. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there a way for me to make it so it tries more times before giving up? I think it is giving up too early and I am getting the same summary of failures about 75% of the time

Comment: Change the value being used to limit to 3 tries.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming **eGCs** is the response with the number.

e.values[2] will always come back as a string (in this case "6.15312E+16"), therefore you cannot convert that to the original number as you loose everything after that last 2. Even if you convert it, the best you can get is "61531200000000000"

Instead, you can pull the value from the spreadsheet.
In the beginning of your onFormSubmit() function add this code:

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
 var eGCs = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 2, 1, 1).getValue(); 
 try {
   eGCs = eGCs.toFixed();
 } catch (e) {
   Logger.log(eGCs);
 }
```

Your **eGCs** will now return as the full number if it's a number, otherwise it will return as text.

If you want the spreadsheet to have the right format when new responses are submitted add this to your code:

```
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 2, 1, 1).setNumberFormat("000");
```

This will convert the new row added by the form in to the correct format. This does not affect the actual value in the spreadsheet, only the way it is formatted.

Comment: Thank you for the advice - I will try this today and report back.

Comment: Hi Ashkin - I was able to get your code working (there is a timestamp column on the left, so I had to change getLastRow(), 2, 1, 1) to getLastRow(), 3, 1, 1). The number is keeping its format in the email, but the sheet is not being converted for some reason. I will work on this part and get back to you.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for my purposes because the eGCs field on the form requires the input of multiple lines of numbers sometimes and it is behaving strangely when this is the case. I appreciate your help, as you have gotten me closer than before, but still is not working as I need it to.

Comment: Apologies for making things difficult - I did not realize that something as simple as keeping data in the same format as it is entered would be such a huge ordeal.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what eGCs can look like?

Comment: The eGCs field can be any combination of letters and numbers and it will often be multiple lines of data.