# Sending e-mail from Google Sheets at specified time on everyday

Tags: google-apps-script

Its any possible to make script which sending us email with all of the one sheet at specified time on everyday?

I have two sheets, which in first my employee is writing price and other data with date (everyday) and second which I created a Summary for me. On second sheet i =today which is searching right date and inserts to my summary.

I would like to give summary (preferably in PDF format or as the content in the message body) at 23:00 everyday.

Comment: I think you will have to have a service running somewhere, once you make that decision it should be pretty easy.  Depending on how much work  you want to put in it could be anything from wiring together a simple Tasker function on your phone to an app hosted in the cloud somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, you can adapt the script in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600638/google-script-copy-to-clipboard-and-mailto-questions/18645451#18645451) on your needs.
Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may want to create a Spreadsheet, a Document template or a HTML table. Then place your HTML in the email body or attach the spreadsheet / document to your summary email. To run it every day at specific time set a [Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/).